# Creating a reusable function across the script for modifying option's value the same as text content

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic

Good day again, seniors.

This was the same code I was working on last time. The question is how would I create a reusable function for any of the option element and modify its value the same as the text content?

In the code below I only had one form but for my real project I do have a lot of forms that contains a select element so I would like to have a reusable function for each.

I tried using the textContent() but it doesn't give me the text content of each selected options.

Again, thank you in advance!

```
<body>

    <form action="" id="form">

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" name="age" id="age">

        <select name="favorites" id="fav">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Favorite Colors</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        </select>

        <select name="location" id="loc">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Location</option>
            <option value="L">Luzon</option>
            <option value="V">Visayas</option>
            <option value="M">Mindanao</option>
        </select>

        <button id="btn" type="submit">OK</button>

    </form>


      <script>
        let list = [];
        const n = document.getElementById("name"); 
        const a = document.getElementById("age"); 
        const clr = document.getElementById("fav"); 
        const loc =  document.getElementById("loc"); 

        
   const addDets = (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            let officials = {
                name: n.value, 
                age: a.value, 
                favColor: clr.value, 
                location: loc.value 
            }
            list.push(officials)
            document.forms[0].reset();
            console.log(list);
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
            document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addDets);
        });
     </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID attributes can often be a nuisance to work with when generating dynamic content of trying, as here, to have a generic function to process similar requests so I find it easier to ignore them and use other methods of identifying DOM elements. You state there are `"a lot of forms that contains a select element so I would like to have a reusable function for each"` - the following uses a single delegated event listener that is bound to the `submit` buttons with class `submit-btn` - the handler captures a reference to all the form elements as an array which is filtered to remove empty elements. The name/value pairs from all form elements (unless empty) are added to an object literal and pushed onto the global `list` array stack for whatever processing you need. This seems fairly `generic`

```js
let list=[];
        
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.classList.contains('submit-btn') ){

    e.preventDefault();

    let form=e.target.closest('form');
    let data={};
    let col=[...form.elements].filter(n=>n.value!='');
      col.forEach(n=>data[n.name]=n.value);
    list.push( data );
    form.reset();

    console.log( list );
  }
});
```

```html
<form name='myform-1'>

    <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
    <label>Age: <input type="number" name="age"></label>

    <select name="favorites">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Favorite Colors</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    </select>

    <select name="location">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Location</option>
        <option value="L">Luzon</option>
        <option value="V">Visayas</option>
        <option value="M">Mindanao</option>
    </select>

    <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">OK</button>
</form>




<form name='myform-2'>

    <label>Height: <input type="number" name="height"></label>
    <label>Weight: <input type="number" name="weight"></label>

    <select name="category">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Favorite Colors</option>
        <option value="Red">Red dfgdf g</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue dfgdf g</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow dfgfd g</option>
    </select>

    <select name="skill">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Location</option>
        <option value="L">Luzon asda sd</option>
        <option value="V">Visayas asd as da</option>
        <option value="M">Mindanao asd as d</option>
    </select>

    <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

---

**update**

Reading the penultimate line from the question I note that you say `"it doesn't give me the text content of each selected options"` which was not accounted for above. To capture that text content the portion of code within the `forEach` loop can be modified like this:

```
  col.forEach(n=>{
    if( n instanceof HTMLSelectElement ) data[ n.name ]=n.options[ n.options.selectedIndex ].text;
    else data[n.name]=n.value;
  });
```

or even:

```
  col.forEach(n=>{
    let value=( n instanceof HTMLSelectElement ) ? n.options[ n.options.selectedIndex ].text : n.value;
    data[n.name]=value;
  });
```

That will assign the name/text rather than name/value to the output object which seems more inline with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the "selectedOptions" property of the select element?

Something like this:

```
const getSelectedOption = (selectElement) => {
      const selectedOption = selectElement.selectedOptions[0];
      const value = selectedOption.value;
      const text = selectedOption.textContent;
      return { value, text };
  }

  const addDets = (ev) => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      let officials = {
          name: n.value, 
          age: a.value, 
          favColor: getSelectedOption(clr), 
          location: getSelectedOption(loc)
      }
      list.push(officials)
      document.forms[0].reset();
      console.log(list);
  }
```